# Application logs to stdout with Shiny Server and Docker

Tags: r, docker, shiny-server

I have a Docker container running a shiny app ([Dockerfile here](https://gist.github.com/stevenranney/678b617084e1cdafca177866125a0541)).

Shiny server logs are output to `stdout` and application logs are written to `/var/log/shiny-server`. I'm deploying this container to AWS Fargate and logging applications only display `stdout` which makes debugging an application when deployed challenging. I'd like to write the application logs to `stdout`.

I've tried a number of potential solutions:

1. I've tried the solution provided [here, but have had no luck.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864028/logging-json-to-stdout-in-shiny-server). I added the `exec xtail /var/log/shiny-server/` to my `shiny-server.sh` as the last line in the file. App logs are not written to `stdout`
2. I noticed that writing application logs to `stdout` is now the default behavior in [`rocker/shiny`](https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny#logs), but as I'm using `rocker/verse:3.6.2` (upgraded from 3.6.0 *today*) along with `RUN export ADD=shiny`, I don't think this is standard behavior for the `rocker/verse:3.6.2` container with Shiny add-on. As a result, I don't get the default behavior out of the box.
3. [This issue on github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/355) suggests an alternative method of forcing application logging to `stdout` by way of an environment variable `SHINY_LOG_STDERR=1` set at runtime but I'm not Linux-savvy enough to know where that env variable needs to be set to be effective. I found [this documentation from Shiny Server v1.5.13](https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#environment-variable-settings) which gave suggestions in which file to set the environment variable depending on Linux distro; however, the output from my container when I run `cat /etc/os-release` is:

[image]

which doesn't really line up with any of the distributions in the Shiny Server documentation, thus making the documentation unhelpful.

4. I tried adding adding the environment variable from the github issue above in the `docker run` command, i.e.,

   ```
   docker run --rm -e SHINY_LOG_STDERR=1 -p 3838:3838 [my image]
   ```

as well as

```
    docker run --rm -e APPLICATION_LOGS_TO_STDOUT=true -p 3838:3838 [my image]
```

and am still not getting the logs to `stdout`.

I **must** be missing something here. Can someone help me identify how to successfully get application logs to `stdout` successfully?

Comment: I think for my scenario, this will be impossible. My docker container is converting an `.Rmd` file to `.pdf` with the `knitr` package. When processing `r` chunks, `knitr` uses `stdout` so it looks like logging Shiny errors to `stdout` will be impossible for me with this container and the `R` code running therein.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the line `ENV SHINY_LOG_STDERR=1` to your Dockerfile (at least, this works with `rocker/shiny`, not sure about `rocker/verse`), such as with your Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/verse:3.6.2

## Add shiny capabilities to container
RUN export ADD=shiny && bash /etc/cont-init.d/add

## Install curl and xtail
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    xtail

## Add pip3 and other Python packages
RUN sudo apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install boto3

## Add R packages
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'tidyverse', 'tidyselect', 'knitr', 'rmarkdown', 'jsonlite', 'odbc', 'dbplyr', 'RMySQL', 'DBI', 'pander', 'sciplot', 'lubridate', 'zoo', 'stringr', 'stringi', 'openxlsx', 'promises', 'future', 'scales', 'ggplot2', 'zip', 'Cairo', 'tinytex', 'reticulate'), repos = 'https://cran.rstudio.com/')"

## Update and install 
RUN tlmgr update --self --all
RUN tlmgr install ms
RUN tlmgr install beamer
RUN tlmgr install pgf

#Copy app dir and theme dirs to their respective locations
COPY iarr /srv/shiny-server/iarr
COPY iarr/reports/interim_annual_report/theme/SwCustom /opt/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/
  
#Force texlive to find my custom beamer theme
RUN texhash

EXPOSE 3838

## Add shiny-server information
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh
COPY shiny-customized.config /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf

## Add dos2unix to eliminate Win-style line-endings and run
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y dos2unix
RUN dos2unix /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Enable Logging from stdout
ENV SHINY_LOG_STDERR=1

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```